# How can an instance communicate with its instantiator?

Tags: java, object, communication, instance

Given a really oversimplified example:

```
Class A {
    B b = new B();
}

Class B {
    //unicorns and what-not
    //Something happens and I want to let A know
    //Yet I don't want to return and exit
}
```

Is there any way that B can communicate with A without Sockets?
By communicate, I mean B sending values to A without A invoking a method on B.

**EDIT**: Thank you for your responses. This following is my follow up question:

If I had the following, and method signal() is called simultaneously by 2 instances of B, this will cause a conflict of every B calling action twice. What can I do to solve it?

```
//Modified from Jon Skeet
public class A {
    private B b[];

    public A() {
        //for loop
        b[i] = new B(this);
    }

    public void signal() {
        //for loop
        b[i].action();
    }
}

public class B {
    A creator;

    public B(A creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    public void action() {
        //stuff
    }

    public void main(String[] args) {

        while(true)
            if(something==true) {
                creator.signal();
            }

   }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you pass a reference of `A` to the constructor of B and operate on this reference?

Comment: What you are asking for is a straightforward example of the *Observer* pattern. Even though people have already given good answers, there may be educational value in knowing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give them both access to the same `Queue`. One puts elements onto it, the other pulls elements from it. If they're in separate threads, one of the [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) implementations should do the trick.

Comment: +1. Message passing is the cleanest way to do this and it also generalizes into other solutions (multiple producers or consumers, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

You'd have to pass `this` into the constructor for B:

```
public class A {
    private B b;

    public A() {
        b = new B(this);
    }
}

public class B {
    A creator;

    public B(A creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }
}
```

Admittedly it's generally not a great idea to let `this` "escape` in the constructor, but every so often it's cleaner than the alternatives.

Comment: If you do this, just make sure you understand the concurrency implications. For instance, `B.creator` is not guaranteed to see any of A's fields that were assigned in the constructor -- not even the final ones. You could have a field in `A`, `private final String name = "Foo";`, and if one of `B`'s methods ever calls `creator.getName()`, it might see `null`. It _probably_ won't, but the JVM would be within its right, according to the JLS.

Comment: @yshavit: Good point - although it *is* guaranteed to see the new fields within the same thread, of course. Sanity still remains in the single thread case, fortunately.

Comment: the day Java introduces within-thread race conditions, I'll move to Scala on account of it being the simpler language. ;-)

Comment: @JonSkeet I posted a follow up question. Would you please help me again?

Comment: @drum: It would help if you'd post *valid code*. Currently you've got an `if` statement in the middle of a class (not in a method) for example. A short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem would help - and it would probably be better off in a separate question.

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right and sorry about that. I've put the if statement inside of main() if that helps.

Comment: @drum: Not really - it's still not a short but complete program.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'll put this in a separate question. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

> // unicorns and what-not

If `A` passes `B` an instance of itself in the constructor, you [ain't need no stinkin unicorns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinking_badges):

```
class B {
    A instantiator;
    public B(A inst) { instantiator = inst; }
}


class A {
    B b = new B(this);
}
```

**EDIT** (to answer the follow-up question)

If you would like to make sure that multiple invocations of `signal` do not modify the the state of `A` concurrently, you should protect its *critical sections* by using `synchronized` keyword. If the entire method represents a single critical section, you can add `synchronized` to method's declaration, like this:

```
public synchronized void signal() {
    //for loop
    b[i].action();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Class A {
    B b = new B(this);

    public void MyCallback(Object o) {

        //Whatever
    }
}

Class B {
    //unicorns and what-not

    private A a;

    // .... assign a in constructor ...

    // wherever 
    a.MyCallback(MyUnicorn);
}
```