# How to avoid conflict in an Observer pattern?

Tags: java, observer-pattern

rThis is a follow up question from [How can an instance communicate with its instantiator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214152/how-can-an-instance-communicate-with-its-instantiator)

If I had the following, and method signal() is called simultaneously by 2 instances of B, this will cause a conflict of every B calling reset() twice. What can I do to solve it?

It's OK to reset if an event happens that causes a reset only if all B's have finish resetting.

```
public class A {
    private B b[];

    public A() {
        //for loop
        b[i] = new B(this);
    }

    public void signal() {
        //tells every B to reset.
        //for loop
        b[i].reset();
    }
}

public class B {
    A creator;

    public B(A creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    public void reset() {
        //very critical operation that should not happen back to back
    }

    public void main(String[] args) {

        while(true)
            if(isBad()==true) {
                //Something bad happen. Tell A to reset everyone.
                creator.signal();
            }

   }
}
```

Comment: Is what happens in `reset()` critical to all instances of `B`? or just the single instance of `B` it is called on?

Comment: The calls are not simultaneous, but sequential, and each B calls `signal` once. Can you make the problem statement clearer? You want to avoid multiple consecutive resets? What behavior do you want?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen It's critical for all B's. For example, all B's as a whole can only call signal() once, and call do so again after resetting.

Comment: Implement different methods for different notification types or for specific observers to be notified.

Comment: It seems to me that `reset()` should only affect a single instance of `B` not all of them.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen no, reset() should signal should call reset() on every B. And because of that, if 2 different B's call signal() around the same time, this will tell A to call B.reset() twice.

Comment: Since all `As` own distinct `Bs` can this not be done by making `A.signal()` `synchronized`?

Comment: What @MiserableVariable said. The only way that two B instances will call signal "at the same time" if is they are in different threads, so making signal syncronized should solve your problem.